# Excel Consider 1.10 and 1.1 as same entry i.e 1.1. I want to 1.1 as unique entry and 1.10 as unique entry

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose I enter:

```
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.10
```

Then what Excel sorting result is:

```
1.1
1.10
1.2
1.3
```

I want unique entry of both numbers.

Comment: the question is not clear need more explanation

Comment: use advanced filter.

Comment: @PraveenDAI just want unique entry to properly work with vlookup. In my case what happens is 1.1 and 1.10 is read same by vlookup formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that mathematically `1.1` and `1.10` is exactly the same.

The only thing you can do is format all these cells as text **before** you enter the values. Then you are able to distinct them with VLOOKUP. But note that you cannot calculate with these text values anymore then.

Note that all the cells used as search matrix in VLOOKUP **and** the search criteria cell needs to be formatted as text **before** you enter any values.

Comment: ya i will convert that whenever i required. thanks buddy

Comment: @Ankit if this solved your issue please consider marking this question as solved.